# Firebase authentication fails with 'invalid phone number' error in Java Android Studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Firebase captcha check fails and prevents authentication.

While Entering to the otp field and verify, it shows the error given below in Java :

[firebase_auth/invalid-phone-number] The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code]. [ Invalid format. ]

I tried numerous ways like entering phone number with country code, with gaps, without gaps but it did't work. I have added the SHA-1 and SHA-256 to the firebase console project & checked all the dependencies in my gradle files.

Here's the java code :

```
package com.example.firebase_phone_verification;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phonenumber, otp;
    Button sendotp, submit;
    String phone, verificationId;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        phonenumber = findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
        otp = findViewById(R.id.otp);
        sendotp = findViewById(R.id.sendotp);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        sendotp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           
            public void onClick(View view) {

                phone = phonenumber.getText().toString();

                if(!phone.isEmpty()){
                    sendOTP(phone);
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a valid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void verifyCode(String code){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId,code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verification successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallbacks =  new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public  void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken){
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted( PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            String code = credential.getSmsCode();
            if(code != null){
                otp.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
                //loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public void sendOTP(String phone){

        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phone)
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setActivity(this)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, use com.google.i18n.phonenumbers

```
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber;

// ...

public void sendOTP(String phone) {
PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phone, 
    "YOUR_DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE");
    if (phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber)) {
        String formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber)
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setActivity(this)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working now. I have one question if I want to determine the region based on the phone number's prefix, should I use null? 
Example : Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phone, 
    null);

Comment: no, just use first 2 digit of your phone number to determine your country code or use country code picker - https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject